# ArchLinux no longer boots after upgrade

Tags: linux, arch-linux

This morning I upgrade my archlinux install. However, when I rebooted my machine I saw the following:

`unable to find root device`

Then I followed the instructions here [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135288]. However was unable to run `pacman -Sy` [no dns right now] since none of  the hostnames could be found.

Then after rebooting I saw:

`mount unknown filesystem type 'ext4'`
`You are now being dropped into an emergency shell`
`sh: can't access tty; job control off`
`[rootfs]#`

Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Boot on the Arch install disk, mount the rootfs under `/mnt` just like during install, `arch-chroot` into it, adjust your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to make sure either the `filesystems` hook is present or manually add the `ext4` module into the modules, and rebuild your initramfs with `mkinitcpio -p linux`, then reboot.

Comment: So I finally got a direct Internet connection and tried that. When I run `mkinitcpio -p linux`. I get that there were errors when building and that some models weren't found. The filesystems  is used in the conf

Comment: When attempting to resume the upgrade from the live cd. It also says that linux-4.7.6-1 package is corrupt

Comment: I was able to downgrade the kernel to long term support and that worked.